# How should we describe the "Aircraft" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) is an odd duck.  I'm not sure it's a ***bad*** tag (certainly there are some generic things that apply equally to a glider, an airship, and a transport-category jet for which "aircraft" may be the best tag), but I'm at a loss how to describe it.

I feel like the tag wiki needs to describe not only what "aircraft" means (we can steal the FAA definition for that), but *how we want the [aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) tag used on the site*.
Anyone want to take a swing at a Wiki entry, or weigh in with ideas?

Comment: [tag:aircraft] seems like a bad idea as the questions that have this tag don't really need it. Until there actually are questions which specifically need an aircraft tag, there is no point keeping it up.

Comment: @AsheeshR That's also a perfectly valid analysis - Do you think we could do away with the tag entirely (remove it from the questions that have it)? The only question that makes me think twice about killing it entirely is the one about [inflight fires](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/391/in-case-of-cabin-fire-why-arent-airplanes-equipped-with-a-mechanism-to-decomp), and I may propose edits removing it from the others...

Comment: That question would be better served by flight-safety, flight-emergency, or fire, or anything else which describes an emergency/fire state during flight.

Answer (score 6):

I say that we get rid of [aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) altogether.  It is a general concept that covers most of the questions that we will have on aviation, and even a question that is general to all aircraft doesn't really need it at all.  For questions that are actually specific to a class of aircraft, they should be tagged [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane), [rotorcraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotorcraft), [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider), [lighter-than-air](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighter-than-air), [powered-lift](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powered-lift), [powered-parachute](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powered-parachute), or [weight-shift-control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-shift-control).

---

### Update:

As of today, [aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) has been removed and is no longer available for use.

Comment: I've [been through](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/97/danny-beckett?tab=activity&sort=revisions) each of the 14 questions in the *aircraft* tag; none of them had a need for it. I've retagged them with more relevant tags. Suggest blacklisting.